# Get custom parameters from aws cognito when it redirects to web application (PingOne as SAML identity provider)

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am validating the user using aws cognito (saml identity provider). I want the email id of user from aws cognito when it is redirecting to my web application using callback feature of cognito.

Currently, i am using the Idp initiated flow to login to my application. When cognito callbacks to my web application URL i am not getting email address.

How  can I get the email id in request?